# Registry - ContextMenu extension of .sdf files

Tags: c#, registry

i want to extend the contextmenu of sdf database-files.
my current source

```
    public static void Create()
    {
        string keyName = ".sdf";
        string contextName = "Das ist ein SDF Test";
        string exe = @"C:\Users\........exe";

        bool isWritable = true;

        try
        {
            RegistryKey classesRoot = Registry.ClassesRoot;
            RegistryKey parentKey = classesRoot.OpenSubKey(keyName, isWritable);

            parentKey.CreateSubKey("shell");

            RegistryKey shell = parentKey.OpenSubKey("shell", isWritable);
            RegistryKey context = shell.CreateSubKey(contextName);
            RegistryKey command = context.CreateSubKey("command");
            command.SetValue("", exe);
            classesRoot.Flush();
            classesRoot.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

now, when i opened the contextmenu nothing is happened...
what goes wrong?

Comment: I need something like that and don't really understand how you solve the issue below. Could you provide the working function ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've said, the context menu opens but nothing happens, right?

If this is the case, it looks like you need to pass the full path of the `.sdf` file into your exe's command line.

So update your exe string variable to be this:

```
string exe = @"\"C:\Users\........exe\" \"%1\"";
```

which will pass in the full path to the `SDF` to your exe.

**UPDATE:**

After researching again, you actually need to read the (default) value of .sdk in `HKCR`.  On my machine it's "Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition Database File".  So you would need to create a new subkey directly below `HKCR` and and put your shell and command subkeys in there.   Check out `.txt` and `.doc` to see an example.

Comment: I don't see the menuItem "Das ist ein SDF Test". Is that right to create the shell key under the file extension .sdf ?

Comment: I need something like that and don't really understand how you solve the issue below. Could you provide the working function ? thanks a lot